# Trying to install Kubernetes in RHEL 8.5 (CRI-O) - getting error

Tags: kubernetes, repository, rhel8, kubectl, containerd

Trying to install Kubernetes in RHEL 8.5 (CRI-O) - getting error Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'devel_kubic_libcontainers_stable: Downloading error(s): repodata/9eaf71711c185fd237f77107b8023a9dce64aacc2d66c301d1b5e21f2b111469-filelists.xml.gz - Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success

Tried dnf clean all - Did not work

Please suggest the alternate workaround to install kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't subscribed for correct repo. Run below commands to enable repo and retry.

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
subscription-manager repos --enable=codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked!

Comment: Please accept this answer so it will be tagged properly in questions queue for others.